# CONVERT_TIMEZONE in redshift is producing the opposite result as expected

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

According to the Redshift Documentation, the syntax should be as follows:

`CONVERT_TIMEZONE ( ['source_timezone',] 'target_timezone', 'timestamp')`

This seems to work fine with standard time zone names, however it doesn't seem to work propoerly when the source timezone is specified as UTC+/- some numbers. In fact it seems to just be working backward.

I am trying to run the following query, for example:

`select convert_timezone('UTC','UTC-8','2019-01-01 00:00:0000')`

The expected result is that this should subtract 8 hours from my timestamp because going from UTC (source) to UTC-8 should take off 8 hours. Instead it is adding 8 hours, and my result is `2019-01-01 08:00:00.000000`. Why is this  happening? Alternatively, converting to a named timezone works as intended:

`select convert_timezone('UTC','America/Los_Angeles','2019-01-01 00:00:0000')`

This query properly displays `2018-12-31 16:00:00.00000` as the result.

So why is it that this function is working backwards? An obvious workaround is to just structure my query backwards, but that seems like an awkward solution. And I would just use a named timezone, but none of the named time zones are explicitly UTC-8 that I know of (Los Angeles for example is GMT-7 during PDT, so that won't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift timezone offsets react opposite to their mathematical operator. Another way to think about it is *losing* (-) time and *gaining* (+) time relative to yourself. If you traveled from a UTC timezone to America/Los_Angeles timezone, the clock goes **back** causing you personally to *gain* (+) eight hours (a whole extra day in the sun!).