# Unexpected result from Redshift TIMEZONE function (convert timestamp column from UTC to another timezone)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Based on my understanding of the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TIMEZONE.html), I am expecting the `TIMEZONE` function to convert any timestamp from UTC (by default) to `'timezone'`.

I know for a fact that the timestamp columns of the server I'm pulling data from are set to UTC. Therefore, if I convert the timestamp column to EST, I should see a five hour difference between UTC and EST (according to [worldtimebuddy](https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/)).

However, when I run the following query

```sql
select
    time_column
    , timezone('est', time_column) as to_est
from
    my_table
order by
    time_column desc
limit 1
```

I get

| sent_at | to_est |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-11-15 17:50:26.280 | 2022-11-15 22:50:26.280 |

If I'm interpreting this correctly, the result is telling me that UTC is five hours *behind* EST, when really, UTC is five hours *ahead* of EST (right?).

In other words, I was expecting

| sent_at | to_est |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-11-15 17:50:26.280 | 2022-11-15 12:50:26.280 |

Why am I seeing a -5 hour difference from UTC to EST instead of +5?

Comment: try https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/CONVERT_TIMEZONE.html

Comment: That did the trick. Would you like to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of timezone use

```
convert_timezone('EST', time_column)
```

That is the way redshift shows in the [manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/CONVERT_TIMEZONE.html)

the syntax is

```
 CONVERT_TIMEZONE ( ['source_timezone',] 'target_timezone', 'timestamp')
```

but the source time zone is by default `UTC`, so you don't need to add it to your code

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT_TIMEZONE('EST', 'IST', '2023-06-20 14:15:33')`


Why do I get result as `'2023-06-20 21:15:33'`?  Shouldn't I get `'2023-06-20 23:45:33'` ?

Comment: redshift works somewhat different https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58549210/convert-timezone-in-redshift-is-producing-the-opposite-result-as-expected